# How to fetch out and in values of edge class records in orientdb using javascript function

Tags: javascript, orientdb

var g=orient.getGraph();

var sqlClassRecords = 'select * from ' + paramClass;

var listRecords = g.command('sql',sqlClassRecords);

return listRecords;

The above lines provide metadata plus out and in values for the edge.Like this:

[
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#46:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "relatesTo",
        "out": "#28:1",
        "in": "#28:2",
        "@fieldTypes": "out=x,in=x"
    }
]

How can i fetch this out (#28:1) and in (#28:2) values using js function. 
listRecords[i].getRecord().field("out") is not working fine. It gives the vertex classes to along with the rids. I want only rids .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another getRecord().field() to get its rids like:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();

var sqlClassRecords = 'select * from ' + paramClass;

var listRecords = g.command('sql',sqlClassRecords);

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < listRecords.length; i++)
{
    var out_ = listRecords[i].getRecord().field('out').getRecord().field('@rid').toString();
    var in_ = listRecords[i].getRecord().field('in').getRecord().field('@rid').toString();
    result.push(new Array("out: " + out_, "in: " + in_));
}

return result;
```